# Excel VBA UpdateLinks using Dir Loop

Tags: vba, sharepoint, excel

When I run the following dir loop, the files that open prompt to update the links even though the code says to update them. Does anyone know why I'm still prompted to update? I have a feeling its related that my directory is sharepoint.

```
Sub OpenProjectFiles()

Dim sFile As String
Dim sPath As String

sPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
sPath = Replace(sPath, "/", "\")
sPath = Replace(sPath, "http:", "")

sFile = Dir(sPath & "\FY*.xls")     

Do While Len(sFile) > 0
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks.CheckOut FileName:=sPath & "\" & sFile
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=sPath & "\" & sFile, UpdateLinks:=3
    sFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: If someone sees a more efficient way to do what I'm trying to do I would love that input as well. Given that I'm pulling from a sharepoint drive, this already takes a while to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out my own question, explained below. **However** I would love insight if there's a better or faster way to cycle through and open these files. Currently it takes about 6 seconds to find,  check out, open and update the links--updating the links doesn't take long since it normally isn't much information to update. And since this routine will normally open about 10-15 files it almost takes about 2 minutes to complete.

Answer: what I realized was the code was in fact updating the links but for some reason the prompt was still popping up. So I just disabled the prompt with:

```
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
```